# É possível contar os dias de validação da licença sem depender da data do sistema?

Tags: java, aplicação-desktop, licença, senhas

Sou novo no mundo da programação.
Com a ajuda de alguns tutorias, consegui construir uma aplicação para gestão de escolas.

Também com a ajuda do canal JavaPlugados consegui construir um sistema que gera a chave de licença e que bloqueia quando esta expirar conforme segue:

```
 //Código que gera a senha


    private void btnGerarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        String data=txtVenc.getText();
        int operacao=(Integer.parseInt(data)+132)/4;
        txtDesblock.setText(String.valueOf(operacao));
    }    
// Código que valida a senha

private void jButtonValidarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        mod.setCodigo(jTextFieldValidacao.getText());
        controle.valida(mod.getCodigo());
        System.exit(0);
    }                                              

    private void jButtonSairActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        dispose();
    }    


//Controle da validação

package br.com.mtsoftware.telas;

import br.com.mtsoftware.dal.ModuloConexao;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author Jelson Fernandes
 */
class ControleValidacao {

    Connection conexao = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    //criando variaveis especiais para conexão com o banco
    //prepared statement e resultSet são frameworks do pacote java.sql
    //e servem para preparar eexecutar as instruções SQL
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    int valida;

    public void valida(String senha) {

        conexao = ModuloConexao.conector();

        try {

            String sql = ("Select (data_vencimento)as vencimento from tbvencimento ");
            // conexao.prepareStatement("Select (data_vencimento)as vencimento from tbvencimento ");
            pst = conexao.prepareStatement(sql);

            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery(sql);
            // pst.executeQuery();
            rs.last();
            valida = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("vencimento"));
            int operacao = (valida + 132) / 4;//(data)+232/7
            int senhaValidacao = Integer.parseInt(senha);
            System.out.println("Operação" + operacao);
            System.out.println("Senha" + senha);
            if (operacao == senhaValidacao) {
                int dia, mes, ano;
                String AcertaMes = null, AcertaDia, ProxSenha;

                SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                Date hoje = new Date();
                String data = df.format(hoje);
                char[] senhachar = data.toCharArray();
                dia = Integer.parseInt("" + senhachar[0] + senhachar[1]);
                mes = Integer.parseInt("" + senhachar[3] + senhachar[4]);
                ano = Integer.parseInt("" + senhachar[6] + senhachar[7] + senhachar[8] + senhachar[9]);
                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, data); 
//                mes+=6;
//                dia=15;
            //    mes+=1;
                if (mes < 12) {
                   dia+=15;
//                    mes ++;
                    //ano++;

                    if (mes < 10) {
                        AcertaMes = "0" + mes;
                    } else {
                        AcertaMes = "" + mes;
                    }

                } else {
                    mes=1;
//                    dia=15;
                   ano++;
                    AcertaMes = "0" + mes;
                }
                if (dia < 10) {
                    AcertaDia = "0" + dia;
                } else {
                    AcertaDia = "" + dia;
                }
                ProxSenha = AcertaDia + AcertaMes + ano;

                //String sql="insert into tbvencimento(data_vencime nto)value(?)";
                //PreparedStatement pst = conexao.prepareStatement(sql);
                pst = conexao.prepareStatement("insert into tbvencimento(data_vencimento)value(?)");
                pst.setString(1, ProxSenha);
                pst.execute();
                // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ""+ProxSenha);
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Senha Invalida. Verifique e Tente Novamente");
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao validar!\nERRO:" + ex);
        }

    }

}

//Sistema de Login com bloqueio  assim que o sistema espira.



w java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
                formWindowOpened(evt);
            }
        });

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 51));
        jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("LOGIN"));
        jPanel1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));

        jPasswordField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jPasswordFieldActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPasswordField.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                jPasswordFieldKeyPressed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel1.setText("Usuário");

        jLabel2.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel2.setText("Senha");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 58, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 44, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(29, 29, 29)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jPasswordField)
                    .addComponent(txtUsuario, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 250, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(txtUsuario, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 31, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 26, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jPasswordField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 29, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2))
                .addGap(29, 29, 29))
        );

        jLabelonoff.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.MatteBorder(null));

        jButton1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/br/com/mtsoftware/icones/LoginButton1.jpg"))); // NOI18N
        jButton1.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.MatteBorder(null));
        jButton1.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jPanel2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 204, 255));
        jPanel2.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.MatteBorder(null));

        jLabel4.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 204));
        jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("RomanT", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel4.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(51, 0, 255));
        jLabel4.setText("TOKES MULTI SOFT");
        jLabel4.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.MatteBorder(null));

        jLabel3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/br/com/mtsoftware/icones/LOGSOFT_Small-3.png"))); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.MatteBorder(null));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 123, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(19, 19, 19))
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 47, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(20, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabelonoff, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 75, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(227, 227, 227)
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 130, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabelonoff, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 67, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 57, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
        );

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jPasswordFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                              

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        logar();
    }                                        

    private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        try {
            String sql = ("Select (data_vencimento) from tbvencimento ");

            pst = conexao.prepareStatement(sql);

            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery(sql);

            while (rs.next()) {
                vencimento = rs.getString("data_vencimento");
                // String dataSistemadataSistema.toString.valueOf(vencimento));
                System.out.println(vencimento);
            }

        } catch (SQLException error) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Erro de Consulta!\nERRO" + error);
        }
    }                                 

    private void jPasswordFieldKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {

            try {
                String sql = "select*from tbusuarios where login=? and senha=? ";
                /*as linhas abaixo preparam a consulta em função do que foi inserido nas caixas de texto
            o ? é substituido pelo coneudo das variaveis*/
                pst = conexao.prepareStatement(sql);
                System.out.println(conexao);
                pst.setString(1, txtUsuario.getText());
                pst.setString(2, jPasswordField.getText());

                /* a linha abaixo executa a querry*/
                //Result rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                rs = pst.executeQuery();

                if (rs.next()) {
                    System.out.println();
                    //a linha abaixo obtem o conteudo do campo perfil da tabela tbusuario
                    String perfil = rs.getString(6);
                    // System.out.println(perfil);
                    //a estrutura abaixo faz o tratamento do perfil do usuário
                    pst = conexao.prepareStatement(sql);

                    rs.isLast();

                    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
                    Date hoje = new Date();
                    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,df.format(hoje));
                    String dataAtual = (String) df.format(hoje);
                    //String dataSistema = rs.getString(vencimento);
                    String dataSistema = String.valueOf(vencimento);
                    System.out.println(dataAtual + "---" + dataSistema);
                    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, dataSistema);
                    /* float valor1=(Float.parseFloat(dataSistema));
                 float valor2=(Float.parseFloat(dataAtual));
                 float valor3=(valor2-valor1);
                 System.out.println(valor3);
                 if(valor2-valor1<=15){
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Faltam" +valor3 +"dias para este sistema expirar");
                 }*/

                    char[] dataAtualVet = dataAtual.toCharArray();

                    char[] dataSisVet = dataSistema.toCharArray();
                    int diaAt, mesAt, anoAt, diaVenc, mesVenc, anoVenc;

                    diaAt = Integer.parseInt("" + dataAtualVet[0] + dataAtualVet[1]);
                    mesAt = Integer.parseInt("" + dataAtualVet[2] + dataAtualVet[3]);
                    anoAt = Integer.parseInt("" + dataAtualVet[4] + dataAtualVet[5] + dataAtualVet[6] + dataAtualVet[7]);

                    diaVenc = Integer.parseInt("" + dataSisVet[0] + dataSisVet[1]);
                    mesVenc = Integer.parseInt("" + dataSisVet[2] + dataSisVet[3]);
                    anoVenc = Integer.parseInt("" + dataSisVet[4] + dataSisVet[5] + dataSisVet[6] + dataSisVet[7]);
                    // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, diaAt);
                    System.out.println(mesVenc);
                    Date data1 = df.parse(dataAtual);
                    Date data2 = df.parse(dataSistema);
                    long difference = data2.getTime() - data1.getTime();
                    float daysBetween = (difference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
                    if ((daysBetween >= 0)) {

                        switch (perfil) {
                            case "admin": {
                                TelaPrincipal principal = new TelaPrincipal();
                                principal.setVisible(true);
                                TelaPrincipal.jMenuBoletim.setEnabled(true);
                                TelaPrincipal.MenRel.setEnabled(true);
                                TelaPrincipal.menCadUsu.setEnabled(true);
                                TelaPrincipal.menPagamentos.setEnabled(true);
                                TelaPrincipal.lblUsuario.setForeground(Color.red);
                                TelaPrincipal.lblUsuario.setText(rs.getString(2));
                                AvaliacaoDoAluno avaliacao = new AvaliacaoDoAluno();
                                TelaPrincipal.jMenuItemPesquiVendas.setEnabled(true);
                                TelaPrincipal.jMenuItemFinancas.setEnabled(true);
                                // AvaliacaoDoAluno.jLabelUser.setText(rs.getString(2));
                                this.dispose();
                                break;
                            }
                            case "Programador": {

                                TelaPrincipal principal = new TelaPrincipal();
                                principal.setVisible(true);
                                TelaPrincipal.jMenuBoletim.setEnabled(true);
                                TelaPrincipal.MenRel.setEnabled(true);
                                TelaPrincipal.menCadUsu.setEnabled(true);
                                TelaPrincipal.menPagamentos.setEnabled(true);
                                TelaPrincipal.lblUsuario.setForeground(Color.red);
                                TelaPrincipal.lblUsuario.setText(rs.getString(2));
                                TelaPrincipal.jMenuItemPesquiVendas.setEnabled(true);
                                TelaPrincipal.jMenuItemFinancas.setEnabled(true);
                                TelaPrincipal.jMenuItemCadLicence.setEnabled(true);
                                TelaPrincipal.jMenuItemProgramador.setEnabled(true);
                                TelaPrincipal.jMenuItemProgramador.setEnabled(true);
                                AvaliacaoDoAluno avaliacao = new AvaliacaoDoAluno();

                                // AvaliacaoDoAluno.jLabelUser.setText(rs.getString(2));
                                this.dispose();
                                break;
                            }
                            case "Aluno": {
                                TelaPrincipal principal = new TelaPrincipal();
                                AvaliacaoDoAluno avaliacao = new AvaliacaoDoAluno();
                                principal.setVisible(true);
                                principal.setVisible(true);
                                TelaPrincipal.jMenuItemMensaldade.setEnabled(false);
                                TelaPrincipal.jMenuBoletim.setEnabled(false);
                                TelaPrincipal.menContratos.setEnabled(false);
                                TelaPrincipal.menPagamentos.setEnabled(false);
                                TelaPrincipal.menCadastro.setEnabled(false);
                                TelaPrincipal.menClasses.setEnabled(false);
                                TelaPrincipal.jMenuItemMensaldade.setEnabled(false);

                                AvaliacaoDoAluno.jButtonSalvar.setEnabled(false);
                                AvaliacaoDoAluno.jButtonAlterar.setEnabled(false);
                                AvaliacaoDoAluno.jButtonExcluir.setEnabled(false);
                                TelaPrincipal.lblUsuario.setText(rs.getString(2));
                                //AvaliacaoDoAluno.jLabelUsuario.setText(rs.getString(2));
                                TelaPrincipal.lblUsuario.setForeground(Color.green);
                                break;
                            }
                            default: {
                                TelaPrincipal principal = new TelaPrincipal();
                                principal.setVisible(true);
                                TelaPrincipal.lblUsuario.setText(rs.getString(2));
                                TelaPrincipal.lblUsuario.setForeground(Color.green);
                                this.dispose();
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                    } else if (perfil.equals("Programador")) {
                        TelaPrincipal principal = new TelaPrincipal();
                        principal.setVisible(true);
                        TelaPrincipal.jMenuBoletim.setEnabled(true);
                        TelaPrincipal.MenRel.setEnabled(true);
                        TelaPrincipal.menCadUsu.setEnabled(true);
                        TelaPrincipal.menPagamentos.setEnabled(true);
                        TelaPrincipal.lblUsuario.setForeground(Color.red);
                        TelaPrincipal.lblUsuario.setText(rs.getString(2));
                        TelaPrincipal.jMenuItemPesquiVendas.setEnabled(true);
                        TelaPrincipal.jMenuItemFinancas.setEnabled(true);
                        TelaPrincipal.jMenuItemCadLicence.setEnabled(true);
                        TelaPrincipal.jMenuItemProgramador.setEnabled(true);
                        TelaPrincipal.jMenuItemProgramador.setEnabled(true);
                        AvaliacaoDoAluno avaliacao = new AvaliacaoDoAluno();

                        // AvaliacaoDoAluno.jLabelUser.setText(rs.getString(2));
                        this.dispose();

                    } else {
                        TelaPrincipal principal = new TelaPrincipal();
//                    AvaliacaoDoAluno avaliacao = new AvaliacaoDoAluno();
//                    principal.setVisible(true);
                        principal.setVisible(true);
                        ValidacaoDoSistema valiadacao = new ValidacaoDoSistema();
                        valiadacao.setVisible(true);
                        Desktop.add(valiadacao);
                        TelaPrincipal.jMenuItemMensaldade.setEnabled(false);
                        TelaPrincipal.jMenuBoletim.setEnabled(false);
                        TelaPrincipal.menContratos.setEnabled(false);
                        TelaPrincipal.menPagamentos.setEnabled(false);
                        TelaPrincipal.menCadastro.setEnabled(false);
                        TelaPrincipal.menClasses.setEnabled(false);
                        TelaPrincipal.jMenuItemMensaldade.setEnabled(false);
                        TelaPrincipal.nenCadCli.setEnabled(false);
                        TelaPrincipal.menCadUsu.setEnabled(false);
                        TelaPrincipal.menCadEmpre.setEnabled(false);
                        TelaPrincipal.menFuncionarios.setEnabled(false);
                        TelaPrincipal.Escola.setEnabled(false);
                        TelaPrincipal.jMenuItemCadProdutos.setEnabled(false);
                        TelaPrincipal.jMenuItemVenda.setEnabled(false);
                        TelaPrincipal.jMenuItemBaixaVenda.setEnabled(false);
                        TelaPrincipal.jMenuItemPesquiVendas.setEnabled(false);
                        TelaPrincipal.jMenuItemFinancas.setEnabled(false);

                    }
                    this.dispose();
                    conexao.close();

                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "usuário e//ou senha inválido(s)");
                }

            } catch (HeadlessException | SQLException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao Logar!\nERRO" + e);
                System.out.println(e);

            } catch (ParseException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }
```

Até aqui ele funciona correctamente. Mas quando altero a data do sistema, como por exemplo: a licença expirou no dia 30/08/2019 e altero a data do sistema para 30/07/2019 ou outra data antes, este inicia normalmente.

A minha questão é a seguinte:
Tem como contar os dias de validação sem depender da data do sistema?

**OBS:** Por ser inesperiente agradeceria se me dessem ua resposta um pouco mais detalhada e siples

Answer (score 0):

Queria adicionar como comentário, mas não tenho reputação, não é uma resposta técnica, então vamos lá:

Ja que não quer acessar a data do sistema, porque não tenta outra abordagem? você pode criar uma variável global privada no sistema e funciona como um contador, e fazer o sistema por "uso", tendo em vista que alguém vá abrir o sistema 1 vez por dia, exclui os sábados e domingos, você consegue chegar a uma data "aproximada", nada que te atrapalhe caso tenha um "contrato".

Se não for usuários específicos você pode criar "pacotes" de acesso, ai a abordagem teria que ser outra, planos com 325 dias de acesso, 648, etc. 
Só que dessa forma você poderia fazer um "decrement" na variável, quando o total de dias corridos fosse igual a 0 você expira o sistema

essa abordagem é bem simples, tendo em vista que sempre que iniciar o sistema, no main você pode alterar a variável.

como você vai guardar ela ai já é algo do seu sistema, DLL, txt, etc.

Outra coisa importante lembrar é que hoje em dia computadores não funcionam se a data estiver errada, da problemas no navegador, etc, então fica um pouco inviável pro usuário alterar a data do computador

Claro que esse é um pensamento meu, me vi na necessidade de abordar alguns termos, não é uma resposta técnica.

Comment: Obrigado  Edson pela ideia e por seres tão rápido a responder. Vou lutar para intender e fazer

Comment: O usuário teria um Sistema com um problema ao retornar a data , tornandon inviável dependendo do sistema,  então isto já seria uma razão para ele não fazer isto , ainda assim você poderia obter a data pela web , deve ter solução para isto.

Comment: @Motta essa solução q eu dei não dependeria da data, mas sim de cada "abertura" do sistema, cada vez q o sistema fosse "utilizado", claro que ele precisaria "forçar" isso, mas se ele não falar, ninguem vai deixar um sistema de gerenciar escola aberto 24horas.

Comment: Concordo , só acho que ele não tem problema pois retorna a data da máquina não é um contorno viável para o usuário fugir da licença  pois o Sistema se torna inútil.